# How to exclude pieces of a record in query count

Tags: microsoft-access

I have to a query that shows training completion dates for all employees. The end result would be the number of employees that attended company trainings each quarter.

I have setup the query to have the user enter a start and end date for it (example 1/1/17 - 3/31/17) which works and a total row which also works. The issue I am having is I only want the count to include the records that fall within that range.

EXAMPLE

```
Employee Name    Training1    Training2    Training3     Training4
Noname            07/06/17      1/12/17      2/15/17        6/6/17
COUNT                    1            1            1             1
```

I know the query above is right because 2 pieces of the record fit the puzzle however, 2 pieces do not. How can I make my query work to only count what fits in the given date range? So COUNT should be 0, 1, 1, 0?

Comment: You are probably going to need to have multiple queries for each piece of the puzzle, then pull them together with another query at the end.  This can go multiple levels deep, depending on the complexity of your data.  It's hard to say exactly here because we don't know what your data look like.

Comment: I was able to figure this out though I am not sure if I did it properly. In the end I only wanted a count of each training provided in a quarter and nothing else. What I did was create a query with a start and end date parameter (the user will chose the range) for each of the trainings located in the training table and added a field called type. This will pull all of the records for a training within the required time and the training name.

Comment: Next I created a union query that pulls the results from the individual queries. I created a query off of my union query and added a column for each training to display the name of the training using OnlyBB: IIf([Type]<>"Bloodborne",Null,[Type]). From this I created a report that had a label for each training and a =count(*) for each column. This gave me exactly what I needed